# Remote Copy of All Traits of a File Except for its Content

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script, tar

Everything described below is done via a Bash script.

I desire to capture the state of a defined set of files on a defined set of remote hosts. The "state" of a file depends on the type of file:

- Regular file: full path, content of the file, mode, owner, group
- Symbolic link: full path of the link itself, the pointed-to path, mode (always 777), owner, group
- Directory: full path, mode, owner, group

When creating a local file to represent the state of a remote file, I distinguish between files with the same full path but which differ on different hosts by appending to the local filename a hash of the traits listed above. I then tar the remote file up (non-recursively, so that in the case of a directory, I get **just** the directory), pipe it though SSH, untar it to my local machine, and mv it to the filename with a hash appended. I use tar because it preserves the traits I care about.

```
HASH=$(ssh -n "$ONE_HOST" "{ cat $ONE_FILE_PATH; stat -c \"%a %u %g %F\" $ONE_FILE_PATH; } | sha512sum")
ONE_HASH=${ONE_HASH:0:20}

TARGET_FILENAME_FOR_COPY="$FILENAME"."$ONE_HASH"
TARGET_PATH_FOR_COPY="$TARGET_DIRECTORY_FOR_COPY"/"$TARGET_FILENAME_FOR_COPY"

ssh -n "$ONE_HOST" \
     "tar -C $DIRECTORY --no-recursion -cf - $FILENAME" | \
     tar -xf - -C "$TARGET_DIRECTORY_FOR_COPY"

mv "$TARGET_PATH_UNHASHED" "$TARGET_PATH_FOR_COPY"
```

This is all in place and working.

Now, for the case of **regular files**, I have an additional need to handle sensitive files whose content I don't wish to copy (though the content will continue to be represented in the hash). My goal is to create the exact same local file I would in the process described above, but that the file should be empty rather than contain the content of the remote file.

Note: I cannot copy the file and then empty the copy of content. Being a sensitive file, its content must not be transferred over the network.

I don't know of a way to get tar to transfer a "shell" of a regular file that has the mode, owner, and group of the file but omits the content in the tarball. Unless somebody knows of a trick to get tar to do this, I think I will have to look at some mechanism other than tar.

How can I most easily accomplish this?

### UPDATE #1

One approach I'm trying is to first make a temporary copy of the file (using **cp -p** to preserve the file attributes I care about) on the remote system, empty that temporary file of content (with **truncate -s 0**), and then copy that to my local machine with tar / ssh as described above. This is awkward and inelegant. I'm hoping to find a way to do this without resorting to the use of a temporary file.

Comment: What's the use case for this?  Once you have this schema of file traits, what do you with it?

Answer (score 0):

You could mount an empty file on top of the sensitive files prior to running tar.

```
touch /tmp/emptyfile
mount --bind /tmp/emptyfile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Oh, that's clever! I like that. But I do see one gotcha... For the duration of the copy operation, the content of the sensitive file would be unavailable to local processes that need it.

Comment: unfortunately, yes, unless they already have an open file descriptor. [This Answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/327572/how-can-i-mount-in-linux-a-filesystem-for-one-process-or-user-only)  shows how you can use pam-namespaces to make user-specific mountpoints, but its a bit beyond the scope of a remote backup.